# Custom modules: Namspace-troubles after converting to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: module, dotnetnuke

I have several custom modules in separated projects (class libraries), not directly in the website-project itself. My predecessor used to work with Visual Studio 2008 in order to edit the modules.

Now, after migrating the project to Visual Studio 2012, I've got strange errors telling me about required references to the DotNetNuke - Assembly. This assemblies reside in the bin-folder of the correspondenting project, nothing has changed there since the migration:

[image]

The references seem to be okay:
[image]

I can hit F12 on e.g. TabController (which resides in `DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs`), this would open the object browser as expected. I can't see what's wrong here. When I compile, the error-list is full of `Reference required to assembly 'DotNetNuke, Version=5.0.0.799, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' containing the type 'DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabInfo'.` or similar.

I remember vaguely that there was "DotNetNuke Project Templates" installed in the old Visual Studio 2008. Could that be an issue, too?

Comment: You might look into why the error says 5.0.0 but your DLL appears to be 5.4.4.2 

I would also highly recommend changing to DNN7 and looking at my module development templates instead of your current approach to development for DNN

Comment: Upgrading to DNN7 is not an option - too many dependencies/modules, and (as often) nobody is willing to pay the workload ;) . I also noticed the mismatch between 5.0.0 and 5.4.4.2. It definitely used to work though that way...

Comment: I would start by removing and re-adding the references, see if that helps.

Comment: You don't happen to have a web.config file in your project's root folder do you? If so, try removing it (DNN modules don't get web.config files)

Comment: I did try re-adding the references, didn't change anything. In fact there is a web.config in the project's root, I removed it for a quick test (I don't understand how that would influence the matter though), didn't help either. As a quick-test, I shortly created a new project, took the content of a class, added the references, and this just compiled fine. Maybe I need to recreate the project, and that's it... strange all the same.

Comment: Try removing the references but this time make sure you also delete all of your temporary internet files, the version mismatch could be indicative of some cached references that are causing problems. I would also look to reference them from the DNN installation (which should match the production installation version), not the bin folder of the project.

Comment: Do you mean the temporary internet files in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files`? Tried that, no effect. The versions seems to be messy though: As C. Hammond already did note, there is a mismatch between 5.0.0 the project is asking for and 5.4.4.2, which is referenced. In the fresh DNN-Installer DotNetNuke Professional 05.01.02 we used to take there is again another version: 5.1.2.49... What actually does work: When I change from .net 2.0 to 4.0 (compile-options), it does compile! Well, maybe I should simply change then the app-pool to 4.0...

Comment: Do you have .NET 3.5sp1 installed?

Comment: @ChrisHammond: I don't think so - why is that needed, when it was compiled with .net 2.0?

Comment: Well with DNN 5.2 3.5sp1 must be installed locally, I was wondering if that might be the cause.